# Drag and Drop polyfill?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for a tool that will allow me to utilize native HTML5 drag-n-drop, as well as fill in support for past browsers.

Does such a thing exist? Modernizr's page (https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills) lists nothing.

Answer (score 4):

What older browsers do you want to support? http://caniuse.com/#feat=dragndrop Says you got support everywhere except Opera.

Comment: The issue is that the Drag and Drop functionality across browsers differs. It would be nice to have a wrapper to provide consistent API - e.g. http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/the_html5_drag.html

Comment: I do not disagree. I'm just saying the basic APIs are there already.  But yeah they certainly can use some massaging to suck less. :)

Comment: Well, it is not supported in ie 7.

Comment: it is almost exclusively supported by desktop browsers and not mobile, which makes it unusable atm depending on what systems/browsers you want to support.

Answer (score 1):

Modernizr now has [Drag drop shim](https://github.com/timruffles/ios-html5-drag-drop-shim) by Tim Ruffles;

[Bernardo Castilho has a polyfill](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1091766/Add-support-for-standard-HTML-Drag-and-Drop-operat) that translates touch events on mobile into drag events